# How Can I pass value from useState into balanceOf function in web3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm creating a DEFI dapp, I want to get the account that is connected with the meta mask using web3.eth.get accounts();

This is what I got when console.log ['0x32F36b36e78E89bdd6efa9e893ec2d87e4E2e3E9'],
I've created use State to push this account to use in React components as props but when I console.log the value of useState I got nothing.

Then if I will get this value inside useState how can I pass it into the balanceOf function?

**useState**

```
const [userAccount, setUserAccount] = useState([]);
```

**the function to get the accounts and get the balance of this account**

```
const blockchainDataLoad = async () => {

const web3 = window.web3;
console.log(userAccount);
// get the Accounts
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
setUserAccount(accounts[0]);




// get the Network Id of The contracts
const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();

// ******************************** Dai Token EuroToken ************************* //

// Get the deployed contract object using the network ID
const daiTokenData = DaiToken.networks[networkId];

if(daiTokenData) {

  // Create a instance of the contract
  const daiToken = new web3.eth.Contract(DaiToken.abi, daiTokenData.address);
  setDTokens(daiToken);

  // get the balance from the investor account
  **let daiTokenBalance = await daiToken.methods.balanceOf(userAccount).call();**
  setDTokenBalance(daiTokenBalance.toString());
  console.log(daiTokenBalance);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the accounts in `useEffect` hook, so when your component renders, your component's state will be already set.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getAccount = async () => {
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      setAccount(accounts[0]);
    };
    // call getAccount() if web3 is defined otherwise you app will break
    web3 && getAccount();
  }, [web3]);
```